# Yocto - Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package

Tags: yocto

I'm using Yocto to install clBLAS library (https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS) using the recipe https://github.com/CogentEmbedded/meta-opencl/blob/master/meta-ocl-common/recipes-graphics/clblas/clblas_git.bb

But I'm getting the below warning everytime & .so file is not present in the built image.

```
WARNING: QA Issue: clblas: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib
  /usr/lib/libclBLAS.so.2.12.0
  /usr/lib/libclBLAS.so.2
  /usr/lib/libclBLAS.so
  /usr/lib/.debug
  /usr/lib/pkgconfig
  /usr/lib/cmake
  /usr/lib/.debug/libclBLAS.so.2.12.0
  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/clBLAS.pc
  /usr/lib/cmake/clBLAS
  /usr/lib/cmake/clBLAS/clBLASTargets-debug.cmake
  /usr/lib/cmake/clBLAS/clBLASConfigVersion.cmake
  /usr/lib/cmake/clBLAS/clBLASTargets.cmake
  /usr/lib/cmake/clBLAS/clBLASConfig.cmake
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
clblas: 14 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
```

How to overcome this warning & make the .so file present in the target's `/usr/lib` folder?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add below lines to your `clblas_git.bb`

```
 FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*"
 FILES_${PN}-dev = "${libdir}/* ${includedir}"
```

For good explanation you will get it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071039/an-example-of-using-files-pn)

Comment: Thanks@ Siva.v , could you please tell me why we need to add include dir

Comment: The answer isn't a really good one and certainly not perfect. It is treating only the symptoms, particularly INSANE_SKIP means the test will be skipped, but the underlying problem will stay. And correct file packaging should happen automatically.
If you can run 'bitbake -e clblas' and post the output (e.g. to pastebin), we might be able to better diagnoze why it isn't working by default.

Comment: It will be helpful if someone could explain how this solution works

Answer (score 20):

If you are using new version of yocto this will help:

```
FILES:${PN} ="name of the dirs is not shipping";
```

In old versions it is `FILES_${PN}`.

Comment: That was my case, good point! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that multilib is not considered correctly during build, looking at cmake files in clBLAS, its using CMake variable for constructing multilib path [SUFFIX_LIB](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L165) and yocto recipe is setting it to be empty [here](https://github.com/CogentEmbedded/meta-opencl/blob/master/meta-ocl-common/recipes-graphics/clblas/clblas_git.bb#L19) however its not encoding the yocto logic for multilib paths. A potential fix would be in recipe as below

```
--- clblas_git.bb.org   2019-12-07 12:41:56.784649031 -0800
+++ clblas_git.bb       2019-12-07 12:42:25.317982206 -0800
@@ -16,7 +16,7 @@ S = "${WORKDIR}/git/src"

inherit cmake pythonnative

-EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DSUFFIX_LIB= -DUSE_SYSTEM_GTEST=ON -DBUILD_TEST=OFF -DPREBUILT_CLT_PATH=${WORKDIR}/clt"
+EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DSUFFIX_LIB=${@d.getVar('baselib', True).replace('lib', '')} -DUSE_SYSTEM_GTEST=ON -DBUILD_TEST=OFF -DPREBUILT_CLT_PATH=${WORKDIR}/clt"

DEPENDS += "virtual/opencl"
```