# Yocto Realsense Building

Tags: yocto, realsense

I'm trying to build a Yocto Hardknott image with Realsense layer for IMX8MP board (Hummingboard Mate). I have received this error:

> ERROR: librealsense2-2.44.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: librealsense2:
> Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
> /home   /home/ubuntu   /home/ubuntu/Documents
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535 Max Range.preset
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535 Max Range With
> Binning.preset   /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535
> Medium Range.preset
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535 Min Range.preset
> /usr/bin/rs-embed Please set FILES such that these items are packaged.
> Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete
> them within do_install. librealsense2: 10 installed and not shipped
> files. [installed-vs-shipped] ERROR: librealsense2-2.44.0-r0
> do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task. ERROR: Logfile of
> failure stored in:
> /home/ubuntu/yocto_hardknott_realsense/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/librealsense2/2.44.0-r0/temp/log.do_package.110367
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/ubuntu/yocto_hardknott_realsense/sources/meta-intel-realsense/recipes-support/librealsense/librealsense2_2.44.0.bb:do_package)
> failed with exit code '1'

I have used this solution:

```
 FILES_${PN} += "${home}/*"
 FILES_${PN}-dev = "${home}/* ${includedir}"
```

from this thread:

[Yocto - Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748528/yocto-files-directories-were-installed-but-not-shipped-in-any-package)

But the error is bigger:

> ERROR: librealsense2-2.44.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: librealsense2:
> Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
> /home   /home/ubuntu   /home/ubuntu/Documents
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535 Max Range.preset
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535 Max Range With
> Binning.preset   /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535
> Medium Range.preset
> /home/ubuntu/Documents/librealsense2/presets/L535 Min Range.preset
> /usr/lib/librealsense2.so   /usr/lib/librealsense2-gl.so
> /usr/lib/pkgconfig   /usr/lib/cmake   /usr/lib/pkgconfig/realsense2.pc
> /usr/lib/pkgconfig/realsense2-gl.pc   /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2-gl
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2/realsense2ConfigVersion.cmake
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2/realsense2Targets-noconfig.cmake
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2/realsense2Targets.cmake
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2/realsense2Config.cmake
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2-gl/realsense2-glConfigVersion.cmake
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2-gl/realsense2-glTargets.cmake
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2-gl/realsense2-glConfig.cmake
> /usr/lib/cmake/realsense2-gl/realsense2-glTargets-noconfig.cmake
> /usr/bin/rs-embed Please set FILES such that these items are packaged.
> Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete
> them within do_install. librealsense2: 26 installed and not shipped
> files. [installed-vs-shipped] ERROR: librealsense2-2.44.0-r0
> do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task. ERROR: Logfile of
> failure stored in:
> /home/ubuntu/yocto_hardknott_realsense/build-xwayland-imx8mpsolidrun/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/librealsense2/2.44.0-r0/temp/log.do_package.128195
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/ubuntu/yocto_hardknott_realsense/sources/meta-intel-realsense/recipes-support/librealsense/librealsense2_2.44.0.bb:do_package)
> failed with exit code '1'

Where is the problem of this?

Thank you so much.

EDIT:

For this case:

FILES_${PN} += "$/home/* /usr/*"

Adding this line solves the error, my mistake, I didn't understand the command.

Comment: What about `FILES_${PN}-dev += ...` instead of a simple `=` ?

Comment: Done. I receive the first error register I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

For this case:

FILES_${PN} += "$/home/* /usr/*"

Adding this line solves the error, my mistake, I didn't understand the command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).