# cmake with bitbake and specific install directory

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I have an issue with installing my target to a specific directory by use of cmake managed build and bitbake (yocto).

At CMakeLists.txt, I want to use the install() section to deploy my target to the specific directory e.g. `/my/specific/directory`.

At CMakeLists.txt this looks like:
`install(TARGETS "${PROJECT_NAME}" RUNTIME DESTINATION my/specific/directory)`.
So, there would be no need at the bitbake recipe to implement an install section.

By default, the cmake uses a `prefix` which derives from bitbake.conf and points to `/usr`. Therefore my target is installed to `/usr/my/specific/directory`.

At cmake documentation I have found to possibilities to modify the prefix:

- Set the environment variable `DESTDIR` to overwrite the prefix
- use `cmake --install . --prefix /my/install/prefix`

In both cases I have no idea, how I have to implement this at the bitbake recipe that this would have an effect, when the `do_install` task is executed.

Has anyone of you a hint here?

Comment: meta-note: @tsyvarev I used to link to the "no thanks damnit" meta post too, but I switched to using https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011/997587. it covers more ground and gets the same point across.

Comment: In your bitbake recipe you should be able to set [EXTRA_OECMAKE](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=extra_oecmake#term-EXTRA_OECMAKE) to pass options to cmake e.g. `EXTRA_OECMAKE= "--install-prefix /mydir"`.

Comment: By doing so, it is deployed to the correct directory on the build system, but it is not deployed to the target by yocto:
`ERROR: <my-app>-1.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: <my-app>-cmake: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /my/specific/directory/my-app`.  This is not the case, if the default prefix is used.

Comment: Maybe try `FILES:${PN} = /my/specific/directory/my-app` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748528/yocto-files-directories-were-installed-but-not-shipped-in-any-package) Either it will be `FILES_${PN}` or `FILES:${PN}` based on which yocto version you are using

Comment: Yes, this works. I am wondering, why this is not necessary, when I use the default prefix. But for the moment it works!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, I will add it as an answer. I am still learning with Yocto, but I have found the IRC channel at #yocto to be quite helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bitbake recipe you should be able to set [EXTRA_OECMAKE](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=extra_oecmake#term-EXTRA_OECMAKE) to pass options to cmake e.g. `EXTRA_OECMAKE= "--install-prefix /mydir"`.

But then with errors regarding `Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:` you can set bitbake to install the files by using:

`FILES:${PN} = "/mydir"`

(Or `FILES_${PN}` for older versions of Yocto). [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748528/yocto-files-directories-were-installed-but-not-shipped-in-any-package).

There may be other ways to achieve the same thing, the #yocto IRC channel can be quite helpful I find.